# Postgresql Auto backup script runs in terminal but does not runs in CRON job on MacOS

Tags: postgresql, cron, backup, pg-dump

I Used Common Postgresql backup script from Automated_Backup_on_Linux:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! $HOSTNAME ]; then HOSTNAME="localhost"; fi
if [ ! $USERNAME ]; then USERNAME="postgres"; fi
BACKUP_DIRECTORY="/Users/xeranta/Documents/AW/"
CURRENT_DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 db_gocampus_unmul \
    > $BACKUP_DIRECTORY/db_gocampus_unmul.sql
else
    pg_dump $1 | gzip - > $BACKUP_DIRECTORY/$1_$CURRENT_DATE.sql.gz
fi
```

**It runs In terminal**

```bash
$ ~/Documents/AW/./dbbackup.sh
```

But does not runs when in set this in CRONTAB in MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6

**I have this error**

> /Users/xeranta/Documents/AW/./backup.sh: line 36: pg_dumpall: command
>   not found

Comment: Can you share the content of this script? But I'd blindly say that the problem is that you don't have pg_dumpall installed in the client.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

 if [ ! $HOSTNAME ]; then
 HOSTNAME="localhost"
fi;
 
if [ ! $USERNAME ]; then
 USERNAME="postgres"
fi;

BACKUP_DIRECTORY="/Users/xeranta/Documents/AW/"
CURRENT_DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
 
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 db_gocampus_unmul > $BACKUP_DIRECTORY/db_gocampus_unmul.sql 
else
pg_dump $1 | gzip - > $BACKUP_DIRECTORY/$1_$CURRENT_DATE.sql.gz
fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that `pg_dump` is on your `PATH` in the interactive shell, but not in the cron job.

You should use an absolute path similar to this:

```bash
PGPATH=/wherever/your/postgres/binaries/are

"$PGPATH"/pg_dump ...
```